# Automator workflow save as

Tags: macos, script, automator

(first time automator user)

I created an Automator workflow (Folder Action) that watches a certain folder for certain file types and moves them to another folder.. I've tested it via Step and Run and it works fine. How do I save this as an app, or at least run on startup?

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you choose File -> Save (or Save As) the Automator action is automagically set up to run whenever a file system event occurs with that folder (hence the requirement to choose the Folder when setting up the action) courtesy of `launchd`.

The workflows themselves are saved in `~/Library/Workflows/Folder Actions/`, which you can be opened up in Automator on other computers and applied to folders.

So there is no explicit way in Automator itself to save the action as an application itself but it is automatically run when the conditions (a file is added to that folder) are met.

Of note you can manage Folder Actions by either clicking on a folder in the Finder and choosing "Folder Actions Setup..." from the Action (Gear) menu or opening `Folder Actions Setup.app` from `/System/Library/CoreServices`

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Automator Workflow to your Login Items.

- Click the the Apple Icon in the upper left corner
- Select System Preferences ...
- In the System section click Accounts
- Select your Account (if not already selected)
- Click Login Items (beside Password which is highlighted by default)
- Click the + and find the Automator file that you saved

***NOTE*: Save the workflow as an application (File > Save As, then choose Application for the File Format option)**

Comment: This works if the workflow was created as an application. However, on Snow Leopard on my machine, choosing File > Save As.. does not allow me to change the type, if say, I created it using the folder action template.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers..

I figured out how to do what I wanted.. I had to right click on the folder that I wanted to apply the folder action to (maybe I don't need to right click on a specific folder or item), and click on Folder Actions, then check the box that said Enable Folder Actions, and enable the scripts from there..

Thanks :)